# the queryParams added in createAuthUrl is not returned

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-php-client

In a Laravel App I try to get permission to save files on a Google Drive. As part of calling the api one can pass query parameters that should be returned.

Like this:

```
$client = new Client([
            'client_id' => config('services.google-drive.client_id'),
            'client_secret' => config('services.google-drive.client_secret'),
            'scopes' => [
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file',
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
            ],
            'redirect_uri' => route('users.integrations.google-drive.connect'), // NOTE: I do add the parameters here
            'approval_prompt' => 'force',
            'access_type' => 'offline',
        ]);


$authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl($client->getScopes(), ['igd' => $idg]);
```

$authUrl is:

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?response_type=code&access_type=offline&client_id=XXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=YYYYYY&state&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&approval_prompt=force&igd=99df36fb-ee4a-4861-8d57-85b0b2905bcd
```

The last parameter is from my app so I send it to Google.

After approving the request the 'callback' url looks like this:

```
https://<my_return_url>?code=4%2F0Adeu5BWppRGhaAsAwDlDxbAMhbFIaEqk1rSHNdMKuQcKe-JXwcTE8fZZmMY3xLSv8XSs7g&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive.file
```

The 'igd' parameter is missing.

Any hint why ?

Thanks.
Kind regards
Steen

Comment: _"As part of calling the api one can pass query parameters that should be returned."_ - can you point to where it actually says that, please?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answer, but it's not 100% correct.

Even with the above, one might not get the query parm back - for whatever reason

What I have found to be working is a call to `$client->setState('my_value')`

then in my callback I check for the 'state' key in the request

I have also found out why you sometins don't get the refresh token, it is due to fact that you have already have some kind of connection.

If you do not get the refresh token, then you can go to the google account and look at connections and then manually disconnect or try to call the `$client->revokeToken()`

Here is a few methods that works for me - my specific use case

NOTE: UserIntegrationGoogleDrive $integrationGoogleDrive is just a record in the db to store some information

```
public function getGoogle_Client()
{
    $client = new Client();
    //NOTE: This is not the credentials to the users Google Drive, but our app
    // So basically, our app asks for permission to save on the users Google Drive
    try {
        $client->setClientId(config('services.google-drive.client_id'));
        $client->setClientSecret(config('services.google-drive.client_secret'));
        $client->setRedirectUri(route('users.integrations.google-drive.callback'));

        $client->addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file');
        $client->setAccessType('offline');
        $client->setApprovalPrompt('force');
    
    } catch (Exception $exception) {
        Log::error($exception->getMessage());
    }
    
    return $client;
}
  
public function connect(UserIntegrationGoogleDrive $integrationGoogleDrive)
{
    $client = $this->getGoogle_Client();
    $client->getCache()->clear();
    $client->setState($integrationGoogleDrive->id);

    return redirect()->to($client->createAuthUrl());
}
    
public function callback(Request $request, string $data = null)
{
    $client = $this->getGoogle_Client();

    if ($request->get('code')) {
        $token = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($request->get('code'));
        $integrationGoogleDrive = UserIntegrationGoogleDrive::find($request->get('state'));

        // We will save the access token, also without the refresh_token, just in case the user wan ut to 'revoke'
        if ($integrationGoogleDrive) {
            $integrationGoogleDrive->access_token = json_encode($token);
            $integrationGoogleDrive->save();
        }

        if (! isset($token['refresh_token'])) {
            Log::error('No refresh token');
            Log::error($request->all());

            return redirect()->route('users.integrations.google-drive.manual-disconnect', $integrationGoogleDrive->id);
        }

        return redirect()
            ->route('users.integrations.google-drive.connect-ok');
    }

    Log::error('Unsupported callback');
    Log::error($request->all());

    return redirect()->route('users.integrations.google-drive.connect-error');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a step you need to exchange the code for the access token

```
// Exchange authorization code for an access token.
$accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
$client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
```